# A puzzling currency

Tags: mathematics

The main international airport in the Kingdom of Treisaria recently installed automatic currency exchange machines.  You can insert banknotes from any of the major world currencies (dollars, euros, yen, pounds, etc.) and receive the equivalent amount in the local currency.  The machines' screens display the current exchange rates (with a small processing fee pre-deducted).

Having spent some time in France prior to my trip there, I had a bunch of Euro notes on me, so that's the exchange rate I'm interested in.  Currently, **one euro buys exactly thirteen Treisarian denari**.

The machines are programmed to always return the minimum number of banknotes + coins needed for the amount.  For example, when the US version needs to give out $60, it's always as 50 + 10, never three 20's.  However, since I wanted more small change, and there was nobody in line behind me to complain about me taking too long at the machine, I fed it my Euro notes one at a time.

- When I put in €5, I receive 1 note and 5 coins.
- When I put in €10, I receive 3 notes and 5 coins.
- When I put in €20, I receive 4 notes and 4 coins.
- When I put in €50, I receive 4 notes and 2 coins.
- When I put in €100, I receive 3 notes and 2 coins.
- When I put in €200, I receive 3 notes and 4 coins.
- When I put in €500, I receive 6 notes and 5 coins.

Treisarian currency has a reputation for being unfriendly to tourists because they don't use the internationally-familiar Arabic numeral system, so people unfamiliar with the local script can't recognize the denominations.

But from the information above, **can you work out what the denominations of Treisarian banknotes and coins are**?  (All are integers, as coins less than 1d have been withdrawn due to inflation.  All banknotes are worth more than all coins.)

**Hint #1**

> There are three denominations of coins and four denominations of banknotes.

**Hint #2**

> The country's name is of Semitic origin.

**Hint #3**

> The denominations are such that the [greedy algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithm-to-find-minimum-number-of-coins/) for change-making is optimal for any amount.

Comment: "*the internationally-familiar Arabic numeral system*" Fun fact: the actual Arabic numeral system today (the one used in languages that use the Arabic alphabet) is completely different from what's referred to in the west as "Arabic numerals" :-)

Comment: Is the highest coin valued less than the lowest note?

Comment: @JMP: Yes.  A corollary is that there is no denomination available in both note and coin form.

Comment: To clarify, is that 13:1 exchange rate _after taking account of processing fees_? In other words, can we safely assume that e.g. "3 notes and 5 coins" is _exactly twice_ "1 note and 5 coins", whatever those notes and coins turn out to be?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Yes.  "1 note and 5 coins" = 65d, and "3 notes and 5 coins" = 130d exactly.

Comment: I think that even if you told us what would happen if the exchange rate changed to **one euro buys exactly fourteen Treisarian denari**, this would still be unsolvable.

Comment: I don't see any reason to think it's unsolvable. It may be hard to solve, though. I am wondering whether it would be contrary to the spirit of the question to solve it by computer.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan; 7 equations in 7 unknowns but we don't know the quantities of the unknowns...

Comment: Yup. But we know that a bunch of things are _positive integers_.

Comment: Seems to me it is more 21 equations with 56 unknowns. But with constraints like positive integers and smallest note greater than largest coin. Quite the challenge!

Comment: A fundamental property in cash money design is that every integer amount should be payable, at least in theory. Can we assume that Treisarians have also followed this guideline?

Comment: @Bass: Yes, every integer amount is payable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Coins: 1, 3, 12
>
>  Notes: 36, 144, 432, 1728

I have to admit that I looked at hint 3, without which I would perhaps not be able to solve it in reasonable time.

With hint 3 it's somehow an easy guess that

> smaller numbers should divide bigger ones.

Starting with the 5 euros and 10 euros, I can bound the value of the smallest note

> between 33 and 41.

so without hesitation I immediately guess

> that the smallest note is 36.

the rest are just try and try (reasonably fast, in several minutes).

After solving it, I think perhaps hint 2 could also be useful, at least to someone with better knowledge than me...

Comment: How did you determine this?

Comment: @dan04 Just added explanations.